# jquery selectors and looping

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I am missing something with the structure of a jQuery object. I need to access the data attribute of an `<li>` item.
This produces the expected output, printing the data object of the last `<li>` to the console:

```
console.log($('#assessment_list li:last').data());
```

But when I try to iterate over the larger object to get the data for each `<li>`, I get an error:

```
for (item in $('#assessment_list li')){
    console.log(item.data());
}
```

throws: "Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'data'". How should I alter the selector in the for loop to hit the `<li>` elements only and not the other keys in the jQuery object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#assessment_list li').each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).data() );
});
```

Comment: @thecodeparadox - I tried this but got a different error about htmlElementLi not having a method .data() again--basically same error but different object identifier. The solution jmar777 suggested below worked. I am a little mystified as to why that one works and your suggestion doesnt, but I am back on track for now. Thanks!

Comment: welp, I figured it out. I failed to make 'this' into a jQuery object, so of course there was no .data method. I'd +1 you but I dont have enough rep yet.

Comment: Maybe you should just your accepted answer to this one.  I appreciate the accept on mine, but this one is a little closer to your original question (and is also correct).

Answer (score -1):

You can get an array of all the data values with `map`:

```
var values = $('#assessment_list li').map(function() {
    return $(this).data();
}).get();

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Yeah I dont understand the downvote; this was really helpful. This is actually the approach I ended up taking. I did set the other answer as accepted because it was closer to the way I asked my original question, but I really wanted the values in an array anyhow, so I used code much your suggestion. Thanks again